# jquery DataTables parent and child rows posted to server as one record instead of two

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, tablerow

I have a problem where `jquery DataTables` creates parent and child rows on resize (responsive DataTable) and I need to save values of inputs from child rows as well as from parent rows and post via ajax to controller action.

Responsive (resized) DataTable:

[image: Responsive DataTable]

Normal (not resized) DataTable:

[image: Normal DataTable]

Currently I am using this jquery function to post data to the server:

```
$('#SaveItemButton').click(function (e) {       
        var arr = [];       
        var rows = $('#ItemTable').find('tbody').find('tr');
        console.log(rows.length);       
        $.each(rows, function (index, item) {           
            var controls = $(this).find('input, select');    
            console.log(controls.length);            
            item = {
                ItemType: controls.eq(0).val(),
                Unit: controls.eq(1).val(),
                Quantity: controls.eq(2).val(),
                Price: controls.eq(3).val(),
                InvoiceDate: $('#InvoiceDate').val(),
                TransferDate: $('#TransferDate').val(),
                TransferPlace: $('#TransferPlace').val(),
                InvoiceDescription: $('#InvoiceDescription').val()
            };            
            arr.push(item);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Item/Add',
            data: JSON.stringify(arr),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                //alert(result);
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {                

            }
        });  
        return false;
    });
```

but when the Datatable is resized it returns two rows which in turn gets posted to the server.

I am retrieving rows from a table via:

```
var rows = $('#ItemTable').find('tbody').find('tr');
```

How can I get all the related parent rows and child rows as one row so I can post that row to the server?

Parent row example:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd parent">
    <td tabindex="0" style=""></td>
    <td class="sorting_1"><input name="ItemType" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
    <td style="display: none;"><select name="Unit" class="form-control defaultpicker"><option>dan</option><option>Komad</option><option>Sat</option>m<option>m2</option><option>m3</option><option>kg</option><option>lit</option><option>pak</option><option>reč</option></select></td>
    <td style="display: none;"><input name="Quantity" class="form-control" type="number"></td>
    <td style="display: none;"><input name="Price" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
    <td style="display: none;"><input name="Total" class="form-control" type="text" readonly=""></td>
    <td style="display: none;"><button type="submit" id="DeleteButton" class="fa fa-times select-row btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-id=""></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Child row example:

```
<tr class="child">
    <td class="child" colspan="2">
        <ul data-dtr-index="0" class="dtr-details">
            <li data-dtr-index="2" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="2">
                <span class="dtr-title">Unit</span>
                <span class="dtr-data">
                    <select name="Unit" class="form-control defaultpicker"><option>dan</option><option>Komad</option><option>Sat</option>m<option>m2</option><option>m3</option><option>kg</option><option>lit</option><option>pak</option><option>reč</option></select>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li data-dtr-index="3" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="3">
                <span class="dtr-title">Quantity</span>
                <span class="dtr-data">
                    <input name="Quantity" class="form-control" type="number" value="3">
                </span>
            </li>
            <li data-dtr-index="4" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="4">
                <span class="dtr-title">Price</span>
                <span class="dtr-data">
                    <input name="Price" class="form-control" type="text" value="1000">
                </span>
            </li>
            <li data-dtr-index="5" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="5">
                <span class="dtr-title">Total</span>
                <span class="dtr-data">
                    <input name="Total" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="" value="">
                </span>
            </li>
            <li data-dtr-index="6" data-dt-row="0" data-dt-column="6">
                <span class="dtr-title"></span>
                <span class="dtr-data">
                    <button type="submit" id="DeleteButton" class="fa fa-times select-row btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-id=""></button>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Controller posted data, `index 0` contains valid data:

[image: Controller posted data]

Code Snippet:

```js
var table = $('#ItemTable').DataTable({
  "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
  "paging": true,
  "pagingType": "full_numbers",
  "searching": false,
  // Solution to responsive table losing data
  'columnDefs': [{
    'targets': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'render': function(data, type, row, meta) {
      if (type === 'display') {
        var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);

        var $el = $('input, select, textarea', api.cell({
          row: meta.row,
          column: meta.col
        }).node());

        var $html = $(data).wrap('<div/>').parent();

        if ($el.prop('tagName') === 'INPUT') {
          $('input', $html).attr('value', $el.val());
          if ($el.prop('checked')) {
            $('input', $html).attr('checked', 'checked');
          }
        } else if ($el.prop('tagName') === 'TEXTAREA') {
          $('textarea', $html).html($el.val());

        } else if ($el.prop('tagName') === 'SELECT') {
          $('option:selected', $html).removeAttr('selected');
          $('option', $html).filter(function() {
            return ($(this).attr('value') === $el.val());
          }).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }

        data = $html.html();
      }

      return data;
    }
  }],
  'responsive': true,
  order: [1, 'asc']
});

// Solution to responsive table losing data
$('#ItemTable tbody').on('keyup change', '.child input, .child select, .child textarea', function(e) {
  var $el = $(this);
  var rowIdx = $el.closest('ul').data('dtr-index');
  var colIdx = $el.closest('li').data('dtr-index');
  var cell = table.cell({
    row: rowIdx,
    column: colIdx
  }).node();
  $('input, select, textarea', cell).val($el.val());
  if ($el.is(':checked')) {
    $('input', cell).prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('input', cell).removeProp('checked');
  }
});

$('#SaveItemButton').click(function() {
  var arr = [];
  var rows = $('#ItemTable').find('tbody').find('tr');
  console.log(rows.length);
  $.each(rows, function(index, item) {
    var controls = $(this).find('input, select');
    console.log(controls.length);
    item = {
      ItemType: controls.eq(0).val(),
      Unit: controls.eq(1).val(),
      Quantity: controls.eq(2).val(),
      Price: controls.eq(3).val(),
      InvoiceDate: $('#InvoiceDate').val(),
      TransferDate: $('#TransferDate').val(),
      TransferPlace: $('#TransferPlace').val(),
      InvoiceDescription: $('#InvoiceDescription').val()
    };
    arr.push(item);
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: '/Item/Add',
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
      //alert(result);
    },
    error: function(errormessage) {

    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="ItemTable" class="table table-hover table-secondary dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" style="width: 100%;" role="grid" aria-describedby="ItemTable_info">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th></th>
      <th>ItemType</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd parent">
      <td tabindex="0" style=""></td>
      <td class="sorting_1"><input name="ItemType" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
      <td style="">
        <select name="Unit" class="form-control defaultpicker">
          <option>value1</option>
          <option>value2</option>
          <option>value3</option>
          <option>value4</option>
          <option>value5</option>
          <option>value6</option>
          <option>value7</option>
          <option>value8</option>
          <option>value9</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style=""><input name="Quantity" class="form-control" type="number"></td>
      <td style=""><input name="Price" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
      <td style=""><input name="Total" class="form-control" type="text" readonly=""></td>
      <td style=""><button type="submit" id="DeleteButton" data-id=""></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.6/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please add to your post, an example of what data is in a parent row and a child row?

Comment: Can you not use relative selectors to get the row with `class="child"` that is the next sibling of the row with `class="parent"`?

Comment: @RyanWilson see the edit above.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you demonstrate that in this example?

Comment: Use `.find('.parent');` instead of `.find('tr');` and the in the loop you can use `var child = $(this).next('.child');` and `if (child) { // add the values of the form controls from the child row };`

Comment: @Dusan It looks like the parent only houses the value you want for ItemType, and the other 3 values Unit, Quantity, and Price are all contained in the child row?? Does that look correct to you?

Comment: @RyanWilson  Actually what happens is when I look at the data that gets posted to the server, the first row seems to contain all the relevant data (all cells are posted correctly) and the second row does not (some data is misplaced and some is missing).

Comment: @Dusan Then it would seem that you don't need to worry about the child rows at all, so just do a check to see if there are rows with class `child`, and if so only grab rows with class `parent` and use those to post, otherwise, use `tr` to get the rows.

Comment: Your child row just seems to be repeating some of the form controls in the parent row (for example you have 2 inputs for `Quantity` - but in the parent row its in a hidden column and it has no value)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I noticed that as well, that is why I asked the OP about whether the parent row housed only the value for ItemType and the other 3 values they need are in the child row, as you pointed out, the one in the parent row is hidden and has no value, so that wouldn't be any use when posting.

Comment: @RyanWilson yes looking at the html it seems I need a child row because the parent row is hidden and does not contain values. But posted row with valid data is index 0.

Comment: @Dusan, Did you try the code I noted above?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you edit the code snippet so i can try your suggestion? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you really cannot. At first DT inject and remove child rows and their content to and from the DOM, making them invisible to simple jQuery selectors. You can target open child rows, but that is all.

Secondly you cannot select multiple elements in pairs. You could have for example `$('tr.parent, tr.parent ~ tr.child')` or similar, but that would be equal to just `$('tr')`. I would go through the API:

```
table.rows().every(function() {
  var $node = this.nodes().to$();
  var item = {
    ItemType: $node.find('input[name=ItemType]').val(),
    Unit: $node.find('select[name=Unit]').val(),
    Quantity: $node.find('input[name=Quantity]').val(),
    Price: $node.find('input[name=Price]').val(),
    Total: $node.find('input[name=Total]').val(),
    InvoiceDate: $('#InvoiceDate').val(),
    TransferDate: $('#TransferDate').val(),
    TransferPlace: $('#TransferPlace').val(),
    InvoiceDescription: $('#InvoiceDescription').val()
  };
  arr.push(item)
})
```

Completely untested. See [JQuery Datatables search within input and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852497/jquery-datatables-search-within-input-and-select) on how to update the DT internals when form controls is changing. Otherwise you will just get return default / original values.